# Django Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, product-quantity

I am trying to build a food ordering web app for a restaurant. I want the customer to be able to select the quantity of items that he/she orders, but I don't know exactly how do I do it. Being the site admin, I want to see what items a customer has ordered along with their quantity. Here is my code snippet:

views.py

```
class Order(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sandwiches = MenuItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Sandwich')
        pizzas = MenuItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Pizza')
        drinks = MenuItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Drink')

        # pass into context
        context = {
            'sandwiches': sandwiches,
            'pizzas': pizzas,
            'drinks': drinks,
        }

        # render the template
        return render(request, 'customer/order.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')

        order_items = {
            'items': []
        }

        items = request.POST.getlist('items[]')
        for item in items:
            menu_item = MenuItem.objects.get(pk=int(item))
            try:
                item_quantity = Quantity.objects.get(pk=int(item))
            except Quantity.DoesNotExist:
                item_quantity = None

            item_data = {
                'id': menu_item.pk,
                'name': menu_item.name,
                'price': menu_item.price,
                'count': item_quantity.count
            }

            order_items['items'].append(item_data)  
            price = 0
            item_ids = []

        for item in order_items['items']:
            price += item['price']*item['count']
            item_ids.append(item['id'])
        order = OrderModel.objects.create(
            price=price,
            name=name,
            email=email
        )
        order.items.add(*item_ids)

        context = {
        'items': order_items['items'],
        'price': price
        }

        return render(request, 'customer/order_confirmation.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='menu_images/')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='item')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OrderModel(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem, related_name='order', blank=True, through='Quantity')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        item_list = dict()
        
        m = Quantity.objects.filter(order=self)
        for each in m:
            item_list[each.item.name] = each.count
        
        return f'Order: {self.created_on.strftime("%b %d %I: %M %p")} - Items= {item_list} '

class Quantity(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=1)
```

and the section in orderr.html where I am asking user to enter quantity looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 p-4">
            <p><h2>Select items to add them to cart (You can change quantity in the cart section)</h2></p>
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="pt-5">
                    {% for drink in drinks %}
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                            <img class="rounded" src="{{ drink.image.url }}" width="150" height="100"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                <div class="form-group form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="form-check-input" value="{{ drink.pk }}">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">{{ drink.name }}</label>
                                </div>
                                <p class="font-weight-bold pl-5">{{ drink.price }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{ drink.description }}</p>
                            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Quantity" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="pt-5">
                    {% for sandwich in sandwiches %}
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                            <img class="rounded" src="{{ sandwich.image.url }}" width="150" height="100"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                <div class="form-group form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="form-check-input" value="{{ sandwich.pk }}">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">{{ sandwich.name }}</label>
                                </div>
                                <p class="font-weight-bold pl-5">{{ sandwich.price }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{ sandwich.description }}</p>
                            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Quantity" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="pt-5">
                    {% for pizza in pizzas %}
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                            <img class="rounded" src="{{ pizza.image.url }}" width="150" height="100"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                <div class="form-group form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" class="form-check-input" value="{{ pizza.pk }}">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">{{ pizza.name }}</label>
                                </div>
                                <p class="font-weight-bold pl-5">{{ pizza.price }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{ pizza.description }}</p>
                            <input type="text" name="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group pt-3">
                    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group pt-3">
                    <label for="name">Email Address</label>
                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="example@company.com" name="email" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
                  Submit order and proceed to cart!
                </button>
            </form>
```

Here is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\docs\GitHub\EasyOrders\EasyOrders\customer\views.py", line 40, in post
    item_quantity = Quantity.objects.get(pk=int(item))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /order/
Exception Value: Quantity matching query does not exist.
```

It is one of the final steps of my project, and I am struggling with this from a long time. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
try:
    item_quantity = Quantity.objects.get(pk=int(item))
except Quantity.DoesNotExist:
    item_quantity = None
```

Comment: i applied your fix and now i am getting this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'`